# select2 does not render after getting it as content via ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I really don't get it...

I have a form with an - input class="select2" - element in it.
Which I call via $(".select2").select2() - this works as usual.

Now the thing is, when I insert this form as a html element that I retrieved via an ajax call, it won't load the select2() function again. I think I understand why this is not working  .... but I DON'T want to do something like

```
success: function(rdata){ 
  $("xy").select2()
}
```

again.

This is my basic function (select2 element will be delivered in $(response).html(rdata)):

```
$(document).on("submit","form.ajax_standard", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    data = $(this).serializeArray();
    url = $(this).attr("action");
    response = $(this).attr("response"); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(rdata){ 
             $(response).html(rdata);
        }
    });

});
```

I would appreciate any advise :)

thx

Comment: you have to use the documented plugin API methods to update, or do what you say you don't want to do

Comment: That's right - you can't select something with jQuery until it is on the page. If your `<select>` element is inside the response from the AJAX request, then you'll have to select it in the `success` handler and invoke select2 on it then.

Answer (score 1):

> but I DON'T want to do something like
>
> ```
> success: function(rdata){ 
>   $("xy").select2()
> }
> ```
>
> again.

I'm afraid that is exactly what you need to do. :)